# How do you make your bot's command in different files?

Tags: javascript

I have a few files right now, but the main file is `main.js`. . . and I want each of my bot's commands in different files. How do I connect those files to `main.js`? This is my main.js file:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { token, prefix } = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Dr. Gamer is now online!');
});

client.login(token);
```

Comment: You are already connecting other files to your `main.js`. What's your actual question?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: I want to put each bot command in a different file, but I need to know how to make it work at the same time as my main.js file

Comment: You already know how to import a file with `require`. What is your actual question? Have you tried to import it? What happened? What's the actual behavior and how does it differ from expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write what is called a "Command Handler" to do this.

Basically, you check the command name to a list of imported commands and call it.

Here's a very simple command handler which imports files from `commands/`

```js
const discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const { token, prefix } = require('./config.json');
const client = new discord.Client();
client.commands = new discord.Collection();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Dr. Gamer is now online!');
    fs.readdirSync('./commands/').forEach(file => {
        if (!file.endsWith('.js')) return;
        const f = require(`./commands/${file}`);
        client.commands.set(file.replace('.js', ''), f);
    });
});

client.on('message', (message) => {
    // assuming ! is the prefix
    if (!message.content.startsWith('!')) return;
    let args = message.content.slice(/ +/g);
    let command = args.shift();
    
    if (client.commands.get(command)) {
        client.commands.get(command).run(client, message, args);
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

An example command:

```js
// ping.js
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
    message.reply("Pong!");
}
```

Take a look at https://anidiots.guide/ for beginner Discord.js stuff, it's a great resource.

Comment: If this helped, please mark it as the accepted answer with the check mark.